# Access: Open current record when opening new form

Tags: forms, ms-access, record

I have multiple forms, that when a person needs to go to the next section to input their piece, the data goes to a new record. I want the data to go to the same record, though until each section is completed.

Fields are: ID, Name, Address, Total hours, and signature. Say the first bit of information is on the initial form (name, address), and then upon command (clicking next), a new form opens with total hours and signature. How do I get the first bit of information to save in record 1, and then the second form information to save in record 2?

the following Works partially now, but the second command on the same form will not work.

```
Private sub command2 click()
If Me.Dirty then me.dirty = false
DoCmd.openform “formname”,,,”[ID]=“ & me.ID
DoCmd.close a form, me.name
End Sub

Private sub command3 click()
DoCmd.openform formname:=“FormName”
End Sub

Private sub command4 click()
If Me.Dirty then me.dirty = false
DoCmd.openform “formname”,,,”[ID]=“ & me.ID
DoCmd.close a form, me.name
End Sub
```

The third private sub command4, even though exactly the same as the others, will not work in my code

Comment: Why do you reference `Me.onclick` instead of `Me.ID`? You can't NOT save the data before going to another form with same record. You could arrange controls on Tab control of a single form.

Comment: Thank you! That worked by changing it to me.ID